# How do you configure Symfony 4 to route alongside other XAMPP (Apache) projects?

Tags: php, apache, symfony, xampp, symfony4

I'm *brand new* to Symfony, so this question will undoubtedly come across as noobish. How do you get Symfony to work with XAMPP? I've read the Symfony documentation for configuring Apache, but can't make heads or tails of it.

XAMPP projects are stored in a single `/htdocs` directory. Each project has its own subfolder and is accessible via the following URL: `http://localhost/project_folder`. At least, that's how I've been doing it.

**My problem is this:** Symfony is different in that its root directory is not front-facing. In other words, to actually access a Symfony 4 site, you need to navigate to the `/public` directory. However, as my local XAMPP (i.e. Apache) server is configured to use a single DocumentRoot (`/xampp/htdocs`), my Symfony project is inaccessible unless I manually append `/public` to the URL.

- **What I want: `http://localhost/symfony_project_folder`**
- **What I have: `http://localhost/symfony_project_folder/public`**

I do not want to set up an entirely separate local server for a single web application, nor do I want to deal with an entirely different URL structure than what is used by my other projects.

*How do I configure Symfony 4 or Apache to properly route to `/public` in this environment?*

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Search for: "apache vhosts"  Of course is this is just for development then use the built in Symfony server.  A simple "php bin/console server:start" is all you need.

Comment: Got it working. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. If you post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad you got it working but I didn't actually give you an answer.  Perhaps you could post one.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there indeed when you create a new symfony project you need to change the  document root of the domain in public folder. A good way to work with symfony would be to use docker which helps you out keep projects separated and you can use phpdocker.io to generate a docker configuration very fast to start working with docker.
Anyway here is an example from symfony manual on how to setup a vhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public
    <Directory /var/www/project/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/project>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

You can read more about web server configuration [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html)